# Time-Ordered Propagator in Euclidean Space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, wick-rotation, analyticity

I saw a paper stating that in Euclidean signature, the Feynman propagator $G_E$ is related to the Wightman functions $W_{\pm}$ via
$$
G_E (x) = \Theta(\tau) \, W_+ (x) + \Theta(-\tau) \, W_- (x) \, ,\tag{13}
$$
where $\tau$ is the Euclidean time, and
$$
W_{\pm}(x) = \int \frac{d^3 \bf{k}}{(2 \pi)^3} \, \frac{1}{2 \omega_k} \, e^{\mp \omega_k \, \tau} \, e^{\pm i \bf{k} \cdot \bf{x}} \, .\tag{14/15}
$$
I'm confused as to why this relation is true in Euclidean space, since the Lorentzian signature step function $\Theta(t)$ cannot be analytically continued to the complex plane.

Furthermore, my attempt at deriving the Euclidean propagator explicitly from
$$
G_E (x) = \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^4} \int d k_E^0 \int d^3 {\bf{k}} \, \frac{e^{-i k_E^0 \, \, \tau} \, e^{i \bf{k} \cdot \bf{x}}}{(k_E^0)^2 + {\bf{k}}^2 + m^2}
$$
has led me to the following result:
$$
G_E (x) = \int \frac{d^3 \bf{k}}{(2 \pi)^3} \, \frac{1}{2 \omega_k} \, e^{-\omega_k \, \tau} \, e^{i \bf{k} \cdot \bf{x}} \, ,
$$
where $\omega_k \equiv \sqrt{{\bf{k}}^2 + m^2}$.
It doesn't seem like I can reproduce the time-ordered result above (the integral also diverges for $\tau < 0$).

I wonder whether I've missed something here.

Comment: All local operators commute in Euclidean signature (since all points are spatially separated) so there shouldn't be any ordering of operators.

Comment: @Prahar Yeah that's what I also thought of after going through other related threads. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: For the integral, you have to distinguish the cases $\tau \gt 0$ and $\tau \lt 0$. In the first case you must close the path in the lower complex half-plane and in the latter case in the upper one. This gives you the result with the Heaviside step functions.

Comment: @Hyperon Hmm... Great point, and I think you're right. I did miss that.